# Why jquery source code don't just pass this to the first argument of its IIFE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, module, window

```
(function( global, factory ) {

  ...

// Pass this if window is not defined yet
}(typeof window !== "undefined" ? window : this, function( window, noGlobal ) {
}));
```

I think `window` equals to `this` when loading jquery in browser. Why not just use `this` instead of `typeof window !== "undefined" ? window : this`.

Comment: hi, don't use the "code snippet tool" for this sort of segment as you can not run it here. Properly format your code instead!

Answer (score 1):

The browser is not the only environment where jQuery may be executed.

It allows jQuery to be loaded in environments where `window` is set but `this` may not refer to the global object.

E.g. in Node with [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom).

Answer (score 0):

If you use this code from, for example, Browserify, then `this !== window`.